# How can I enable the Software Centre to also install recommended packages?  

Tags: software-center

How can I enable Ubuntu Software Centre to also install recommended packages?

Currently, it seems just to install the software I selected whcih sometimes does not work without recommended software.

Comment: Could you give us an example of this? What package? What add-on?

Answer (score 1):

Installing recommended packages is the default behaviour, so unless you disabled it there's some other reason why those apps won't work.

Note that "suggested" packages aren't installed by default, with no way to turn that on that I know of.

Comment: > Note that "suggested" packages aren't installed by default, with no way to turn that on that I know of.


Is this in development?
In synaptic we could also install required and recommended packages.

Comment: @Timmie It doesn't call `suggested packages`, it calls `Added` or `Additions`. This packages doesn't install by default because are aggregated (puglins), so it is not and it will not be chosen for install. Just do click on the rectangle and press `install`..