# Does optional add-ons automatically install on apt-get install command?

Tags: apt, software-center

When I open the Ubuntu Software Center, on some software pages I see under the "Optional add-ons" some additional packages(?) that are automatically selected for install.

The question is - when I run the "sudo apt-get install" command for a certain software, does it automatically also install those optional add-ons?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Depends on whether they are recommended or suggested. Recommended packages are installed by default, suggested aren't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I enable the Software Centre to also install recommended packages?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/83131/how-can-i-enable-the-software-centre-to-also-install-recommended-packages)